# ASP MVC Init model's foreign data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a the following model that has the "locations" as **foreign key** from table locations

```
 public class Restaurant
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string  name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Locations> locations { get; set; }
}
```

why when ever i init my model Restaurant the locations is set to `null` except if i called the location DB context before calling the attribute 
example :

```
 var t = db.Restaurant.First(); // the locations attribute is null
 db.Locations.First(); // calling the locations db context
 t; // now t.locations has one record without adding anything just loading the DB
```

how can I make it when ever I call location it automatically initiate the query ...

Answer (score 0):

modify your get accessor.

```
get
{
  if(!_locations.Any()
  _locations.Add(db.Locations.First();
  return _locations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking for is lazy loading feature. What do you use for data access (I guess EF). If you use EF you should enable lazy loading. But be careful, due to lazy loading can be evil feature.

So far, if you want locations all together with restaurant object you can automatically fill your locations in Restaurant constructor:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public Restaurant() {
       // fill locations
    }

    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string  name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Locations> locations { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public Restaurant()
    {
        locations = new List<Locations>();
    }

    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string  name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Locations> locations { get; set; }
}
```